# Capturing words within spaces and quotation marks?

Tags: c, string, token, tokenize

The idea, explicit in the title, is to capture words within spaces and quotation marks here's an example of the input we are dealing with:

```
Input:

The Brown "Fox Jumps Over" "The Lazy" Dog
```

Currently my code can capture words within spaces, as many of you know, a basic strtok() is enough. Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main () {
   char command[BUFSIZ];
   char *token;
   fgets(command,BUFSIZ,stdin);
   
   token = strtok(command, " ");

   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
    
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

And as expected, my code prints the following:

```
Current Output:

The
Brown
"Fox
Jumps
Over"
"The
Lazy"
Dog
```

But the whole idea and problem is to get the following output:

```
The
Brown
Fox Jumps Over
The Lazy
Dog
```

All the help is welcome and I thank you in advance.
*(PS: The included libraries are the only ones allowed.)*

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I find it hard to believe the output you printed came from that program

Comment: @w08r You're right. I accidently copied an old version. I already edited it to the current *working* code.

Comment: Isn't the basic idea how to solve this relatively obvious? `strtok()` won't do any longer, we must read char by char. Probably don't even need `fgets`. Spaces (probably: any whitespace) separate words, except when "within" quotes. How do we detect that? Well, when the first `"` comes along, we are within; after the next one we are no longer "within", and the normal space separation applies; after the next one after that we are "within" again, ignoring space, and so forth. Abstractly spoken: A quote toggles the "within" mode, and we start with "not within".

Comment: There is probably a specification gap: Do you consider quoted strings spanning newlines a single word? Is it an input format error? Do newlines terminate quoted words, even without quote?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The idea is to create a command line input reader to read user commands. Some of them will have the quotation marks due to how the program is supposed to work and some wont. Since this is actually my first project ever in C I'm trying out some stuff and I figured using a tokenizer would work well since it would "token" all the commands a user can input straight away in the command line.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Every command has an initial letter:
c, p, q, l, i. Some of these take no more arguments and some do. From those that do, some of them can have "quoted strings" as arguments or not. Every command line will be in a single line only and it's granted that it will respect the input type for each argument.

Comment: just a bit of somewhat useless info, in C++ you do it like this: `std::cin >> std::quoted(word);` You can even insert a literal quote by typing `\"`.

Answer (score 2):

This program works for your input, it employs a tiny state machine that prevents splitting between quotes.  `strtok` is pretty limited for cases more complicated than a single split token IMO:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void prn(char* str) {
    printf("<< %s >>\n", str);
}

int main(){
    char command[BUFSIZ];
    char state = 0;
    char *start = NULL;
    char *cur = NULL;
    
    fgets(command, BUFSIZ, stdin);
    start = cur = command;
    
    while (*cur) {
        if (state == 0 && *cur == ' ') {
            /* space outside quotes */
            *cur = 0;
            prn(start);
            start = cur+1;
            cur++;
        } else if (*cur == '"') {
            /* quote found */
            *cur = 0;
            if (state) {
                /* end quote -- print */
                prn(start);
                
                /* skip past spaces */
                cur++;
                while (*cur == ' ')
                    cur++;
            } else {
                /* in quote, move cursor forward */
                cur++;
            }
            /* flip state and reset start */
            state ^= 1;
            start = cur;
        } else {
            cur++;
        }
        if (cur - command >= BUFSIZ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Buffer overrun\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    /* print the last string */
    prn(start);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
➜ echo -n 'The Brown "Fox Jumps Over" "The Lazy" Dog' |./a.out
<< The >>
<< Brown >>
<< Fox Jumps Over >>
<< The Lazy >>
<< Dog >>
```

[edit: tidied following feedback, printing delimited to catch any sneaky spaces creeping through]

Comment: The last 2 lines printed are `"Dog\n"` and `"\n"`.  The `*cur == ' '` should look for other white-space too.

Answer (score 0):

This also uses a state machine. Unlike the other answer, it ignores quotes inside words by having 3 states, `empty`, `word`, and `quote`. It also has error detection, and handles tabs and multiple spaces, but is more complex.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

/*!conditions:re2c*/

static int scan(char **text, const char **token) {
    char *YYCURSOR = *text, *yyt1, *open = 0, *close = 0;
    enum YYCONDTYPE condition = yycempty;
    assert(text && token);
    /*!re2c /**/
    re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;
    re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;
    re2c:define:YYGETCONDITION = "condition";
    re2c:define:YYSETCONDITION = "condition = @@;";
    re2c:define:YYGETCONDITION:naked = 1;
    re2c:define:YYSETCONDITION:naked = 1;

    space = [ \t\v\n];
    nul = "\x00";
    quote = "\"";
    */
    for( ; ; ) { /*!re2c /**/
        <empty> nul { return *token = 0, 0; }
        <empty> space+ { continue; } /* Leading space. */
        <empty> quote @open :=> quote
        <empty> @open * :=> word

        <word> nul { return *token = open, 1; }
        <word> @close space
            { *close = '\0'; *text = close + 1; *token = open; return 1; }
        <word> * { continue; }

        <quote> @close quote
            { *close = '\0'; *text = close + 1; *token = open; return 1; }
        <quote> nul { return errno = EILSEQ, 0; }
        <quote> * { continue; }
        */
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    char command[BUFSIZ], *input;
    const char *token;
    errno = 0;
    if(!(input = fgets(command,BUFSIZ,stdin))) goto catch;
    while(scan(&input, &token)) printf( "%s\n", token );
    if(errno) goto catch;
    goto finally;
catch:
    success = EXIT_FAILURE;
    if(errno) perror("capture");
finally:
    return success;
}
```

Uses [re2c](https://re2c.org/) as `re2c -W -T -c -o main.re.c main.c` to generate the code.